# Facebook iOS query

Tags: ios, facebook

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    //some best practice boiler plate code for storing important stuff from fb
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    //now load all my friend's birthdays
    NSMutableDictionary * params = 
                         [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"select birthday, name, uid, pic_square from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) order by name", 
                         @"query",
                         nil];

    [self.facebook requestWithMethodName: @"fql.query" andParams: params andHttpMethod: @"POST" andDelegate: self];
}
```

this only gets me the first friends details . how to i get details of all the friends .

Comment: This may be of interest; https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

Comment: Hi thanks for answering . But i really don't understand as the output dint give me any links or stuff . Also if you can give me the code for request:didLoad class and how i can retrieve the friends information.